# Can a H.264 raw stream be divided into two individual parts?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, video-encoding

If i got a incomplete H.264 raw stream,can i cut the tail of that stream by checking the NALU's payload type of `end_of_seq_rbsp`,so the first part of that stream can be decoded and played.

Any Answers Will Be Helpful.

Comment: You can generally cut an h264 stream anywhere , and anything before it will still play.

Comment: @szatmary That is,decoder will handle it? Thanks a lot!!!